# How to refresh jTable after adding record w/o page refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, html, jtable

Here is my add driver button

```
  $( "#addDriver" ).button().click(function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var dn = $("input[name=driver_name]").val();
    var ds = $("input[name=driver_status]").val();
    var dataString = 'driver_name='+ dn + '&driver_status='+ ds;

            //Here is where im trying to load it but it's not working 
    $('#driversTable').jtable('load');


    if(dn == '' || ds == '' )
    {
        alert("Fill up all Fields with \'*\'");
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processDriver.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
        if(!data.error && data.success) {
                alert(data.successMsg);

                $("input[name=driver_name]").val('');
                $("input[name=driver_status]").val('');

            } else {
                alert(data.errorMsg);
            }
        }
        });
    }
  });
```

And here is my jTable init

```
$("#driversTable").jtable({
        title: 'Drivers',
        actions: {
            listAction: "getAllDrivers.php",
        },
        fields: {
            did: {
                key: true,
                list: false
            },
            dID: {
                title: 'Driver ID',
                width: '7%'
            },
            dName: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '7%'
            },
            dStatus: {
                title: 'Status',
                width: '12%'
            }
        }
    });

    $('#driversTable').jtable('load');
```

I want it to be right after adding a new record i want the table to refresh without refreshing the page. I tried the **load** and **reload** functions of jtable is not working or am i just putting them on the wrong place of my code?

Answer (score 0):

Insert Data First Then Reload.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processDriver.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
    if(!data.error && data.success) {
            alert(data.successMsg);
            $('#driversTable').jtable('reload');//<== Reload after Success
            $("input[name=driver_name]").val('');
            $("input[name=driver_status]").val('');

        } else {
            alert(data.errorMsg);
        }
    }
    });
```